# Probability you play the piano song at least 8 times before getting it correctly 4 times?

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

Question: You are working on a difficult passage from a new piece you are learning on the piano.You wish to play it correctly 4 times before calling it a day. If you have a probability of 2/3 of playing it correctly on every attempt, and the attempts are independent (unfortunately!), what is the probability that you attempt to play it at least 8 times?[image]

So I'm taking the compliment of in order to figure out what is the probability that you attempt to play it at least times by doing 1-prob of getting it right 4 times in under 8 attempts.

I went though this case by case. The first case is in 4 attempts I play the song correctly 4 times.

The second case is getting it right in 5 attempts. I know automatically the fifth attempt I have to play the song correctly or I would have stopped early (would fall into the previous case) thus that leaves 4 combinations to play.

The third case is getting it right in 6 attempts.Again the 6th attempt I must get the song correct or I would have stopped earlier which leaves 10 combinations... and so on.

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: It would be nice if you could put your argument into _words_.

Comment: The formulas look OK according to how you describe the cases. You leave us guessing which formula produces which of the decimal numbers in the final sum. You also have something that looks like an equation, but the sum before the equals sign is obviously _not_ equal to the number after the equals sign. I think you forgot to show us the step where you subtract something from $1.$

Comment: In general, for writing mathematics here, see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: If you have a probability of "$2$" of playing it correctly, you're doing something amazing, since the greatest possible probability is $1$.

Comment: @JohnHughes where do I have probability of 2?

Comment: In the third sentence that you wrote: "If you have a probability of 2 of playing it correctly on every attempt..."

Comment: Why have you asked the same question twice? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966403/what-is-the-probability-that-you-attempt-to-play-it-at-least-8-times-in-order-to

Answer (score 2):

The approach mostly looks good, though there may be some errors in the arithmetic as you try to evaluate the various terms. So you might want to check that.
(It is often helpful to write step-by-step equations where you have a complete, correct equation at each step, rather than writing a formula at some random location on the paper, going off somewhere to get a number from it, and writing the number in some other random place on the page.
I suspect you may have the correct numbers, just written in an unexpected sequence.)

The one thing that looks like an obvious mistake is that you are adding up the cases where you play exactly four times, exactly five times, exactly six times,
exactly seven times, or **exactly eight times.**
The sum of those probabilities is the probability to finish in **eight or fewer** tries, and when subtract the sum from $1,$ you get the probability that you have to do **more than eight** tries, that is, **nine or more.**

So the first thing I would do is stop including the eighth try in your sum.
Then the sum will actually represent playing the piece correctly four times in
**under** eight attempts.

Comment: thank you very much!! Sorry my work is a little all over the place. I will be more organized next time.

Comment: I recommend organization partly because I find I cannot even keep track of my own work if I skip writing down some of the steps. Maybe your short-term memory is so much better than mine that you don't need this, but I suspect most of us find it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In a direct answer, I think you're on the right track.  I'll share my method, which sounds similar to yours, but it treats the "history" as an all-at-once rather than try to combine runs of 4, 5, 6, etc. separately.

The question wants to know how likely is it that you have to go *at least as many* as 8 tries to succeed.  In problems like this, it's useful to think of what has to happen to require an eighth try.

In your previous 7 tries, you must have succeeded precisely 3 times, no more, no less, and in no particular order.  Think about how many combinations that is, and what fraction that is to the total number of outcomes in 7 tries.

That gives you a fraction of the likelihood of getting to the 8th try, and you have a 1/2 odds of getting it right on the 8th try.

Can you work it from there?